# How to remove 4digitnumber/2digitnumber with preg_replace?

Tags: php

How to remove 4digitnumber/2digitnumber with preg_replace ?

I try this code :

```
<?
$data1 = 2018/01;
$data2 = preg_replace('%\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/%', '', $data1);
echo $data2;
?>
```

Comment: show desire output

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: You’re aware that your `$data1` variable contains only `2018`, right?

Comment: The output is nothing, i want to remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've edited your code. the problem was your regular expression was looking for 
/1234/12/
instead of 1234/12
(where 1234 can be any 4 digit number, and 12 can be any 2 digit number).

and your `$data1` variable should be a string

```
$data1 = '1232018/01abc';
$data2 = preg_replace('/\d{4}\/\d{2}/', '', $data1);
echo $data2;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many `regex` you can perform here. The `easiest` one is to clear all but the `/` like this:

```
<?php
    $data1 = '2018/01';
    $data2 = preg_replace('/[^\/]+/', '', $data1);

    echo $data2;
    // prints '/'
?>
```

---

If you `always have 4 digits before` the `/` and `two digits after` you could also make a `regex list`:

```
<?php
    $data1 = '2018/01';
    $regexList = array('/^[\d]{4}/', '/[\d]{2}$/');

    $data2 = preg_replace($regexList, '', $data1);

    echo $data2;
    // prints  '/'
?>
```

here the `whole regex list will be exected`. The first list element is the `regex` for the first half of the string and the second for the second half.

The `^` matches the beginning of the string (except when it's inside `[ ]` then it's a char negation) while the `$` matches the end.

---

If you wanted `to delete any amount of digits` before and after the `/` you would do this:

```
<?php
    $data1 = '206789678918/0179679';
    $regexList = array('/^[\d]*/', '/[\d]*$/');

    $data2 = preg_replace($regexList, '', $data1);

    echo $data2;
    // prints  '/'
?>
```

The `*` identifier matches `0 or more` of the elements. If you wanted at least one number to be present before or after the `/` then you would use `+` which matches `at least one` of the elements.

Comment: Thank for your answer, your code 100% work :) but flynorc code also work and more simple

Comment: @Ivan86, good job explaining the possibilities. I'd say that is a more complete answer. upvote in my books :) what I would still add is the explanation that he should escape the / whenever he wants to match (replace) the "2018/12" string completely

Comment: @flynorc You are right, I didn't understand he wanted to remove all the characters including the `/`. I thought only digits. Thanks

Comment: Michael I didn't understand your question, I thought you wanted to leave the  `/` but delete all digits.

Comment: I want to remove them all, every string that contains 4digitnumber/2digitnumber ( include the "/"' )

Comment: Well, I'm glad you got it working. I thought the question was more complicated. It's much easier to match the whole string than it is to skip the `/`. I'll leave my post for educational purposes, but @flynorc has the right answer.